# i saw the code of starting other apps from my app.but i came to K little bit ..i need some detailed ebooks on intents and start activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i saw the code of starting other apps from my app.but i understood little bit ..i need some detailed ebooks on intents and start activity ON ANDROID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the book I used to learn about Android. It walks you through code and how to build apps but long before it goes into detail about the architecture and what you spefically asked for (intents and activities). It's really good and explains all the code and what each line does, and also helps you install and set up Eclipse (which I found to be quite difficult).

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hello-Android-Introducing-Development-Programmers/dp/1934356565/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1289556713&sr=8-2

Hope this is what you meant by your question. Had a hard time understanding :P

Comment: i could not understand intent.setAction(); not only this there are more stuffs like this related to intents and activity's....